# MobileFirst 8 : Can we remove libauthjni.so file?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

In MobileFirst 8 Android project, there are libauthjni.so file.

[image]

These files appear to be used for [Application Authenticity](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/ru/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/application-authenticity/)

If we do not use this feature, use only the following features：

1. [UserAuthenticationSecurityCheck](http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/ru/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/user-authentication/)
2. [SecurityCheck](http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/ru/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/creating-a-security-check/)
3. [Certificate Pinning](http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/ru/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/certificate-pinning/)
4. [Encrypting the web resources](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/t_cord_web_encrypt.html)
5. [DirectUpdate and application access/notify/disabled](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/ru/foundation/8.0/application-development/direct-update/)

In this case, can we remove libauthjni.so file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you do not use Application Authenticity you can remove these files. However, can you say why you'd want to do that ?

Comment: Thank you. This libauthjni.so file may have security vulnerabilities : OWASP Reverse Engineering and Code Modification Prevention